# onClick is not firing

Tags: reactjs, onclick, crud, mern

I'm teaching myself CRUD in MERN stack and I've come across a bug. The onClick inside GET function is not firing, it only fires after multiple times of clicking.
Here's the code:

`

```
function GetData() {
    try{
      useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/app/profile', {
        })
        .then((response)=>{
          const userdata = response.data;
          setUser(userdata)
          console.log(userdata)
        })
      },[])
      if (User.length > 0){
        try{
           return User.map((user) => {
            return(
              <div style={{ display:'flex', marginTop:'1em'}}>
                <div style={{ marginLeft:'15em', width:'500px'}}>
                  <h style={h2}>{user.name}</h>
                </div>
                <div style={{ width:'350px' }}>
                  <h style={h2}>{user.email}</h>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={()=>{alert('update');}}>UPDATE</button>
                  <button onClick={()=>{alert('delete');}}>DELETE</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        } catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
      }
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

`

I spent a whole day looking for a solution but the problem is still there.
Here' my package.json:

`

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
  }
}
```

`

Also just for testing, when I place the buttons outside on the GET function they work fine. But they won't work inside GET where I need them to be placed.

Comment: Hi. There is no `onClick` inside of any GET function. What are you trying to do? Run the query when the UPDATE button is clicked? 

The `useEffect` hook is used to perform side effects in functional components. Check it out on the React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). It is not used as a callback function for an event like `onclick`.

Additionally, you should not be wrapping your react function components in `try/catch`.

Comment: It is hard to follow. What is `GetData`: a function inside a component (if so, how is it called)? A whole component (some variable declarations are missing)? What is the point of wrapping _everything_ in try-catch? Also, your `if (User.length > 0)` test is run synchronously, before the HTTP call returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to return webpage JSX two times, it get the function stuck in loophole. It is ideal to have only single return in a function. Try to remove the single return. Hope it may help!!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of refactors needed in your code.

I have refactored this here https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-yalow-glp5dq?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [User, setUser] = useState();

  function GetData() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {})
      .then((response) => {
        const userdata = response.data;
        setUser(userdata);
        console.log(userdata);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    GetData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {User &&
        User.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: "1em" }} key={user.id}>
              <div style={{ marginLeft: "15em", width: "500px" }}>
                <h5>{user.id}</h5>
              </div>
              <div style={{ width: "550px" }}>
                <h5>{user.title}</h5>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    alert("update");
                  }}
                >
                  UPDATE
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    alert("delete");
                  }}
                >
                  DELETE
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```